# Get all item li ul tag using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I want get attribute href all li item using Jsoup.
[image]

Comment: Please share what you have done so far

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and enhance your question accordingly, stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials about this out there, it's easy to find those with just some googling. Do that.

But here's some code that might point you in the right direction.

First connect to get an `Document` object to work with

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect({url}).get();
```

Then I think you can grab all `<li>` items with a specific class like:

```
Elements listItems = document.select("li.item");
```

With that you can iterate through all items and grab the `<a>` tags, and then extract the `href` from those.

```
for (Element listItem : listItems) {

    Element linkTag = listItem.getElementsByTag("a").first();

    String url = linkTag.absUrl("href");

}
```

*Note. You probably have to trial and error this, haven't tested it.*